# Definite integral of $1/(2\sin^4x + 3\cos^2x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

I have $f = \frac 1 {(2\sin^4x + 3\cos^2x)}$ which area should be calculated from $0$ to $\frac{3\pi}2 $.

I noticed that $$\int_0^{\frac{3\pi}2} f \,dx= 3\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} f \,dx$$

I tried to calculate this integral with the Weierstrass substitution:

$t = \tan{\frac x2}$

I got this integral:

$$6\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^2)^3}{32t^4+3(1-t^4)^2} \,dt$$

My second try: I divided and multiplied on $\cos^4x$.

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} f \,dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac1{(2\tan^4x + \frac3{\cos^2x})\cos^4x}  \,dx$$

$t = \tan x, dt = \frac{dx}{\cos^2x}, \cos^2x = \frac1{\tan^2 x +1}$

I got:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{t^2+1}{2t^4 + 3t^2 + 3} \,dt$$

Nothing of this helps me to calculate the area by getting primitive function.

Comment: https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%282sin%5E4x%2B3cos%5E2x%29&lbound=0&ubound=3pi%2F2&simplify=1

Comment: I would've gone for the last substitution as well and since a rational function always has a primitive function (you can use a partial fraction decomposition), the problem is 'in principle' solved. However, the calculations can get nasty and the denominator doesn't have an easy/nice factorization to do this 'by hand'. Are you sure you're supposed to (be able to) do this exercise by hand?

Comment: @StackTD Yes. Should I just use partial fraction with complex roots?

Comment: You could, or because it is bi-quadratic in $t$, you expect a factorization of the form $2(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b)$. By inspection (look at the constant term) you immediately have $b=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and then $a$ follows as $\sqrt{\sqrt{6}-\frac{3}{2}}$. I repeat: not fun to do by hand. Unless we miss a clever alternative approach to this particular integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc, for a good idea, but your answer that I calculated is not correct. I tried to solve it myself with getting these coefficients (A, B, etc.). This is my solution that based on yours:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac {1+\frac1{t^2}}{2t^2+\frac3{t^2}+3} \,dt$$

I. We can write $2t^2+\frac3{t^2}+3$ as

$(\sqrt2t+\frac{\sqrt3}t)^2 - C^2$, where $C = 2\sqrt6 - 3$

or $(\sqrt2t+\frac{\sqrt3}t)^2 + D^2$, where $D = 2\sqrt6 + 3$

II. $1+\frac1{t^2}$ can be represented as $A*(\sqrt2+\frac{\sqrt3}{t^2}) + B(\sqrt2-\frac{\sqrt3}{t^2})$

We can find A and B by opening brackets and solving the system of two linear equations.

$A = \frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{2\sqrt6}, B = \frac{\sqrt3-\sqrt2}{2\sqrt6}$

III. Ok, now we can write our integral as:

$$ A\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt2 + \frac{\sqrt3}{t^2}}{(\sqrt2t-\frac{\sqrt3}{t})^2+D^2} \,dt + B\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt2 - \frac{\sqrt3}{t^2}}{(\sqrt2t+\frac{\sqrt3}{t})^2-C^2} \,dt$$

Look at the first integral in this sum:
$u = \sqrt2t-\frac{\sqrt3}{t}; du = \sqrt2+\frac{\sqrt3}{t^2}$

We have:

$$A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^2+D^2} = \frac{A}D\arctan{\frac{u}D}\Big|_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \frac{A}D\pi$$

Look at the second integral:
$u = \sqrt2t+\frac{\sqrt3}{t}; du = \sqrt2-\frac{\sqrt3}{t^2}$

We have

$$B\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dv}{v^2-C^2}=0$$

Then, the result is $$\frac{A}D\pi = \frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{2\sqrt6\sqrt{2\sqrt6+3}}\pi$$

The answer to my based task is:

$$3\frac{A}D\pi = 3\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{2\sqrt6\sqrt{2\sqrt6+3}}\pi$$

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+\frac32 t^2+\frac32}$ we'll first write $t^4+\frac32 t^2+\frac32=(t^2+at+b)(t^2-at+b)$ with $a:=\sqrt{\frac32-\sqrt{6}},\,b:=\sqrt{\frac32}$. Hence $$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^2+1}{(t^2+at+b)(t^2-at+b)}=\frac{1}{2ab}\int_0^\infty\sum_\pm\frac{a\pm (1-b)t}{t^2\pm at+b}dt\\=\frac{1}{2ab}\left[\sum_\pm\left(\pm\frac{1-b}{2}\ln(t^2\pm at+b)+\frac{a(1+b)}{\sqrt{4b-a^2}}\arctan\frac{2t\pm a}{\sqrt{4b-a^2}}\right)\right]_0^\infty\\=\frac{1+b}{2b\sqrt{4b-a^2}}\left[\sum_\pm\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\mp\arctan\frac{a}{\sqrt{4b-a^2}}\right)\right]\\=\frac{\pi(1+b)}{2b\sqrt{4b-a^2}}=\frac{\pi(2+\sqrt{6})\sqrt{2\sqrt{6}+1}}{6\sqrt{23}}.$$(You'll want to double-check my arithmetic at the end.)

Answer (score 2):

Let me bother about $$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1+1/t^2}{2t^2+\frac{3}{t^2}+3}dt.$$ Then
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ A \left(\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{t^2}\right)+B \left(\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{t^2}\right)}{2t^2+\frac{3}{t^2}+3},~ A=\frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{6}},~B=\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{6}}.$$ Next, we re-write the denominator two ways: $$ I=\frac{A}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{t^2}\right)}{\left(t\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{t} \right)^2-C^2} dt + \frac{B}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\left(\sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{t^2}\right)}{\left(t\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{t} \right)^2+D^2} dt. $$ Here $C^2=2\sqrt{6}-3, D^2=2\sqrt{6}+3.$
Now let the twin transformations as  $u=(t\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}/t)$ and $v=(t\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}/t).$ Then $$I=A \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^2-C^2} + B  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dv}{v^2+D^2}.$$ Thse are thw standard ones to be done next.

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral of your function is given by $$-{\frac {\ln  \left( -\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}\tan
 \left( x \right) +\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+2\, \left( \tan \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) \sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2
}}{120}}+{\frac {\ln  \left( -\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}
\tan \left( x \right) +\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+2\, \left( \tan \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) \sqrt {3}\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3
}}{60}}-1/30\,{\frac {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}
\sqrt {3}+6}}\arctan \left( {\frac {-\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}
\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}}
 \right) }+1/30\,{\frac { \left( 2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3 \right) 
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}}{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}\arctan \left( {
\frac {-\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan \left( x
 \right) }{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}} \right) }+1/3\,{\frac {
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}}{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}\arctan \left( {
\frac {-\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan \left( x
 \right) }{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}} \right) }+{\frac {\ln 
 \left( \sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}
\tan \left( x \right) +2\, \left( \tan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \right) \sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}}{120}}-{\frac {\ln 
 \left( \sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}
\tan \left( x \right) +2\, \left( \tan \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \right) \sqrt {3}\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}}{60}}-1/30\,{\frac {
2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}\arctan
 \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan
 \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}} \right) }+1/30\,
{\frac { \left( 2\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3 \right) \sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}}{
\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}\arctan \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2\,
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {4\,
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}} \right) }+1/3\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}}{
\sqrt {4\,\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}\arctan \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2\,
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}-3}\sqrt {2}+4\,\tan \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {4\,
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {3}+6}}} \right)}
$$
solvable by the tan-half angle substitution.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that it is the primitive function of $1/(2\sin^4x + 3\cos^2x)$. In Wolfram i got $1/3(\sin^2x + \cos^4x)$ by d/dx.

Comment: I have made a typo i have written $$\frac{1}{3(\sin(x)^4+\cos(x)^2)}$$ instad of $$\frac{1}{2\sin(x)^4+3\cos(x)^2}$$